# Rails default_scope prevents my rails app from starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a user model and i want to define a `default_scope` for ordering like so:

```
default_scope(order(:firstname))
```

Nonetheless this is preventing my rails server from starting, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your scopes with blocks:

```
default_scope { order(:firstname) }
```